# how to refund partial amount in paypal adaptive payment

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-adaptive-payments

I am working on paypal adaptive payment & i need to refund with API , i am able to refund full amount but i also need to refund partial amount

reference url which i am using:https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/adaptive-payments/Refund_API_Operation/

eg- total amount made at time of payment is 100 & i need to refund only 50.00

i try following code/api parameters

```
-H "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-PASSWORD: api_password" 
-H "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-SIGNATURE: api_signature" 
-H "X-PAYPAL-REQUEST-DATA-FORMAT: NV" 
-H "X-PAYPAL-RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT: NV" 
-H "X-PAYPAL-APPLICATION-ID: your_app_id "  https://svcs.sandbox.paypal.com/AdaptivePayments/Refund  -d  
"requestEnvelope.errorLanguage=en_US 
&transactionId=AP-95V43510SV018561T0"
```

& try these inputs to set refund amount

```
&amount = 50.0
```

&

```
&amount = XS:50.0
```

but none of these working just refund the full amount

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A little correction on your request payload, "AP-95V43510SV018561T0" is a pay-key value (obtained from the Pay api response), the name pair should be 
`payKey = AP-95V43510SV018561T0`

A partial refund payload with minimum parameters would be like this, say if you have just made a $100 transaction and is about to do a $50 refund:

```
requestEnvelope.errorLanguage = en_US
detailLevel = ReturnAll 
payKey = AP-95V43510SV018561T0
receiverList.receiver(0).email = receiver@paypal.com
receiverList.receiver(0).amount = 50.00
currencyCode = USD
```

And the API response:

```
responseEnvelope.timestamp=2015-08-06T07:39:08.861-07:00
responseEnvelope.ack=Success
responseEnvelope.correlationId=2e7007b68f85b
responseEnvelope.build=17603431
currencyCode=USD
refundInfoList.refundInfo(0).receiver.amount=50.00
refundInfoList.refundInfo(0).receiver.email=receiver@paypal.com
refundInfoList.refundInfo(0).refundStatus=REFUNDED
refundInfoList.refundInfo(0).refundNetAmount=48.05
refundInfoList.refundInfo(0).refundFeeAmount=1.95
refundInfoList.refundInfo(0).refundGrossAmount=50.00
refundInfoList.refundInfo(0).totalOfAllRefunds=50.00
refundInfoList.refundInfo(0).refundHasBecomeFull=false
refundInfoList.refundInfo(0).encryptedRefundTransactionId=96U15993F0258151X
refundInfoList.refundInfo(0).refundTransactionStatus=COMPLETED
```

Comment: Thanks for help , it's working properly in case of parallel payment but in case is chain payment not working properly EG- if buyer/sender made payment to 3 recovers receiver1 = $90, receiver2 = $90 & receiver(primary) = $20, when i process refund 0f $10 from each receivers from API ,API return status COMPLETED for each, primary receiver get refund of $10 & $10 from secondary receivers , but buyer get refund of only $10.what is the problem can you help me

Comment: Better if you could paste the exact request payload & response here, of the refund API call. And be noted that in this use case, the secondary & the subsequent receivers will need to grant permission (of refund operation) to the API caller

Comment: here i asked a new question with details of API & response http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31980280/how-to-refund-partial-refund-in-paypal-adaptive-payment-chain-method